# Where is the practical application of functions in the field of computer Science

Tags: functional-programming

I wanted to know the use of functions in the field of computer science. I mean to say the functions not as a method, the original concept of functions in mathematics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at functional programming http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_programming